# How to show that maximizing "chip EV" is the equilibrium strategy in winner-take-all poker

Tags: game-theory

This question is based on poker, but you don't need to know anything about poker to analyze it.

A while ago I [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4663802/exponentials-of-stochastic-band-matrices) over on math.SE how to prove that the probability of winning a head up poker match was equal to the percentage of the chips the player holds. In my simplified setup, we imagine that the players' holdings at round $t$ are $X_t \in \{0, 1, \dots, N\}$, and that $X_t$ is a martingale. $0$ and $N$ are absorbing states, and all other states are transient. The original question was what the probability of ending in state $N$ is, if you start in state $k$. The answer to this is $k/N$.

This matches poker players' intuitions: in winner-take-all games it is widely stated that you should play to maximize "Chip EV", the expected number of chips you will have after a given hand. I'm interested in proving that this actually is the case at the Nash equilibrium.

I'm worried that what's going on here is circular:

1. If the players only care about maximizing chip EV, both players will act to cause the EV of each round to be 0
2. This will imply that the probability of winning while holding $k$ dollars out of $N$ is $k/N$
3. This seems to imply that you should maximize chip EV

When I've written it out like this, it obviously seems circular. To remove the circularity, I think I need to show that if one player has $k$ dollars and the other has $k - N$ dollars, their strategies at equilibrium will still be identical.

This is very plausible, since (this is the one poker fact you need to know) if one player has $k < N/2$ chips, and the other has $N - k$ chips, the set of actions available to them in the hand of poker they play are identical to the case where they both only have $k$ chips. Does anyone know if there's a way to convert this property of the subgames into a statement about the optimal subgame strategy?

Comment: I’m not convinced “you don’t need to know anything about poker to analyze [this question]” is true. I bet you could come up with artificial poker-like games where maximizing chip EV *is not* the optimal strategy for winning. So you have to use some properties of (or reasonable assumptions about) the actual game of poker somewhere.

Comment: @SamHopkins That's a fair point. The poker community's arguments on the topic do not involve any poker specific details as far as I know, so I would consider a demonstration of such a game interesting.

Comment: *the set of actions available to them in the hand of poker they play are identical to the case where they both only have k chips* - but the payoffs aren't. If the low player loses k chips, they lose the game. If the high player loses k chips, they're still in it.

Comment: I suspect that the question is not well posed, because it is not clear what "CHIP EV" is. To define the expected value, you need to know the strategies of the other players. Could you define the WHOLE GAME: how many players there are, what are their sets of actions, what is the stage outcome matrix that dictates how $X_t$ changes? Without this information, I do not know how to interpret your question.

Comment: @Eilon I now see the question is well-posed and agree with the answer. "Chip EV" just refers to each round as resulting in a number of chips for each player, which is zero-sum and in [-k,k] where k is the smaller of the two players' starting chips in the round. Since by the last paragraph, each round is a symmetric game (with the "number of chips" utility function), each player has a strategy guaranteeing E[chips] >= 0.

Comment: Though I wondered if the way antes or blinds work in poker would change the conclusion.

Comment: @usul Actually I did gloss over that, since the blinds make each round asymmetric. You can't even save it by considering pairs of rounds, since being the small blind first is advantageous. I don't even know how to get started on the question with that complication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many game theoretic arguments, the circularity is only apparent. The key is to look at the game from the perspective of just one of the players (who follows the proposed strategy), and to allow the opponent to deviate from the proposed strategy.

Assume that from each state, each player has some strategy that guarantees an expected chip gain of at least $0$ (and that the game is guaranteed to eventually end in one of the absorbing states $0, N$). Suppose that player 1 commits to a strategy that maximizes their expected chip gain, while player 2 follows whatever strategy they like in response. Then the number of chips owned by player 1 is a *submartingale*: the expected number of chips in the future (given what has happened so far) is always at least as large as the current number of chips held by player 1, regardless of how player 2 responds.

By Doob's optional stopping theorem, the expected value of the number of chips held by player 1 at the end of the game is at least the initial number of chips held by player 1, which is $k$. So we can conclude that the probability that player 1 wins must be at least $k/N$, regardless of how player 2 responds, as long as player 1's strategy guarantees that their expected chip gain is at least $0$ in each round of the game.

Since player 2 can follow a similar strategy to limit player 1's win-rate to $k/N$ by ensuring that player 1's expected chip gain is at most $0$ in each round of the game, maximizing expected number of chips is a Nash equilibrium. Furthermore, if player 2 makes the mistake of allowing player 1 to have a strictly positive expected chip gain, then player 1 will strictly increase their probability of winning as a result, so maximizing the expected chip gain is even a strict Nash equilibrium.

Comment: It seems like the subgames being symmetric, zero-sum, and non-deterministic (so that the payout isn't just always 0) is sufficient.